# I get a nil when I use self in block.But self does't free

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, swift-block

I use an viewController which inherit BaseViewController. The function "monitorNetworkStatus()" is invoked in BaseViewController's method "viewDidLoad".

```
private func monitorNetworkStatus() {
        ReachabilityManager.shared.startMonitoring { [weak self] (status, presentingVC) in

            print(self?.description)

        }
    }
```

ReachabilityManager is a singleton。The startMonitoring function like this

```
    func startMonitoring(reachabilityStatus: @escaping (_ status: AFNetworkReachabilityStatus, _ presentingVC: UIViewController?) -> Void) {

        AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared().setReachabilityStatusChange { [weak self] (status) in
            if status != self?.networkStatus {
                // Only notify when status toggling between reachable and not reachable
                if (self?.networkStatus == .notReachable &&
                    (status == .reachableViaWiFi || status == .reachableViaWWAN)) ||
                    status == .notReachable {
                    reachabilityStatus(status, self?.getPresentingViewController())
                }

                self?.networkStatus = status
            }
        }

        AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared().startMonitoring()
```

When net status changes it will print nil occasionally.

Answer (score 3):

The `startMonitoring` method takes in a closure which holds a `weak` reference to your view controller's instance. This closure lets `ReachabilityManager`'s singleton instance know what needs to happen whenever network status changes.

Passing a weak reference to this closure ensures that the memory occupied by your view controller instance can be freed when it is no longer being used, thus preventing a potential memory leak.

At times, your view controller will get garbage collected when it is dismissed (or no longer being used elsewhere), but the singleton instance of `ReachabilityManager` (which outlives your view controller) will still call the closure that was passed to the `startMonitoring` method earlier. Since your view controller has been garbage collected, `self` will be `nil` in this case and you will see `nil` being printed occasionally.

Were the closure holding a `strong` reference to your view controller, you would probably be facing memory leaks, since your view controller will not get garbage collected when dismissed.

Comment: The view controller doesn't dismiss and get garbage collected. I stay in this viewController.

Comment: Maybe you are presenting another view controller, which inherits from `BaseViewController`, and then returning to your current view controller after dismissing it. In this case, the other view controller would replace the closure and `ReachabilityManager` will notify this other view controller instead of the desired view controller. Try moving the call to `monitorNetworkStatus()` to `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` of the `BaseViewController`

Comment: If other controller is created I wouldn't print nil.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `ReachabilityManager.startMonitoring`. It is likely called more than once. Also add a method `deinit` on every object that calls `startMonitoring` and place a breakpoint there. You'll see something like what Mayank is saying, where `deinit` is called and then a network change occurs before another call to `startMonitoring` is made. Without your full program, it's hard to know exactly how this happens, but it is very certain that it is happening.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks a lot, I have found the problem. The singleton's method "startMonitoring" is only invoked once.